# Can't open Powerpoint presentation from Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file that works fine on my pc running Win XP, Excel 2003. PowerPoint resides in Office 11. Needed to go to another PC same Files but PowerPoint is in Office 10.  The file I have "WORKED" fine on mine but will not open PPT presentations on all PC. So I need a different way to open them. I was using a Shell call to open and that was good. I found a snippet from Ron DeBruin which kind of works. It partially fails on the open though. Here is the code that is important. PowerPoint Does open as an application but the file itself does not open IN the Application. I get an **Automation Error** and in the same popup **Unspecified Error**. Is there a better way for Excel to find where PowerPoint resides and open it that way?

```
    Public Sub Start_Viewer(ProgFile)

      Dim objPPT As Object
      Dim PrgName As String

      Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
      objPPT.Visible = True

      PrgName = Mid(ProgFile, InStrRev(ProgFile, "\") + 1, InStrRev(ProgFile, ".") - InStrRev(ProgFile, "\") - 1)

      objPPT.Presentations.Open FileName:="S:\Lab\EHS\SAFETY\" & PrgName & "\PPT\" & PrgName & ".ppt"
      Workbooks.Open FileName:="S:\Lab\EHS\SAFETY\" & PrgName & "\Quizzes\" & PrgName & " Quiz.xls"

    End Sub
```

**objPPT.Presentations.Open** is the part that fails. I added **FileName** aafter open as I saw it in another post someplace. It fails with or without that.

Original working code for MY PC only.

```
      Public Sub Start_Viewer(ProgFile)

      '  This works for PowerPoint in this location only and on my work PC
      '  It fails on other pcs at work when PowerPoint resides elsewhere.

      '  ProgFile is the path passed from the calling subroutine _
         and opens the PowwerPoint Presentation for that file
      RetVal = Shell("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\PPTView.exe " & Chr(34) & ProgFile & Chr(34), 1)

      Watched = MsgBox("Have you finished the presentation?", vbYesNo, "Verify Presentation Watched")
        Select Case 6
                 ' PrgName is JUST the extracted FileName (no path no extension) to give me folder names
                 PrgName = Mid(ProgFile, InStrRev(ProgFile, "\") + 1, InStrRev(ProgFile, ".") - InStrRev(ProgFile, "\") - 1)
                 Workbooks.Open FileName:="S:\Lab\EHS\SAFETY\" & PrgName & "\Quizzes\" & PrgName & "Quiz.xls"
               Case 7
                 Exit Sub
        End Select
      End Sub
```

Comment: You said it worked using a `Shell` object. Why did you abandon that way of doing it?

Comment: Specifically, what does the error message say?  On what line does it occur?  `Presentations.Open` is a valid call.  If you look at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746171.aspx), you'll see that `Filename` is the first parameter, and the only required parameter of the argument.  You can omit or keep the `Filename:=` as that is just a parameter identifier.   When debugging, just before getting to the line with the `Presentations.Open` method, what is the value of `PrgName`?  Have you checked this path is valid?  Is the extension correct?

Comment: @Bond the OP wrote "the file I have "WORKED" fine on mine but will not open PPT presentations on all PC. So I need a different way to open them. "  I am assuming this is why he abandoned the `Shell` object, but I'm not positive.  @Valhalla_33 - can you post the original code you had?

Comment: @CBRF23 Yes that is the reason I abandoned the original code. I cannot be 100% certain the **Shell** cmd will work everytime as I saw today. I will try an post the original code when back at work.  As for your first comment: it did work on MY pc at work but not on others.  As for the value of **PrgName** that value is passed (ProgFile) as a path from the calling subroutine and it DOES pass it in full. As you can see PrgName is obtained by extracting the filename from the path and removing the extension. When the program errors out  **PrgName** DOES have the correct value when I cursor over it.

Comment: At exactly what line do you get the error?  What is the exact error message?

Comment: objPPT.Presentations.Open FileName:="S:\Lab\EHS\SAFETY\" & PrgName & "\PPT\" & PrgName & ".ppt"

Comment: @CBRF23 will post original code in a minute. Found a copy of it at home.

Comment: Have you tried `objPPT.Presentations.Open  progFile`?  Your original script  was specifying the file to open as this argument, why did you change it ?

Comment: @CBRF23 That fails to.  Error now is **Method 'Open' of Object 'Presentations' Failed

Comment: That's not a very helpful error message :/ can you screenshot the folder where the file exists?

Comment: No idea how to post a image. Sorry. If I knew how to PM you I might b able to do it that way.

Comment: In your original post, you can edit it, there is an insert image button.  Or, just go to imgur.com, click upload image, ctrl-v to upload the screenshot from clipboard, and the comment back here with a link.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check [EzPaste](http://www.excel-premiumutilities.com) for automating the process of pasting from Excel to PPT

Comment: I Am not trying to **PASTE** anything from Excel to the PPT file. I am trying to Open an existing PPT file **FROM** Excel.